# How to create different version numbers for same apk files with different cpu architecture

Tags: android, performance, gradle, apk

In order to reduce Apk size i need to create different apk for each CPU architecture. This is the approach i am using;

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi'
        universalApk false
    }
}
```

This creates 2 apk files, the size of both are lower than `universalApk`. So this fix my apk size problem.

Now the issue is how to upload both of them in `Play store`.

[This](https://developer.android.com/google/play/publishing/multiple-apks.html#Rules) stated that the version code of both `apk's` should be different.

Before adding updated apk to `playstore`, i open app level `build.gradle` and update `versionCode` attribute;

```
    defaultConfig {
      versionName "1.0.2"
      versionCode 78
    }
```

So now when i will create multiple apk's, both will have same `versionCode`. 
My question is how can i assign different versionCode to both of the generated apk's or do i need to create both apk's one by one after changing their `versionCode` value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it is possible

Here is my gradle file which creates 3 different apk file with different version code. You will find valuable comments in gradle file below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword ''
            storeFile file('/Users/anasabubacker/StackOverflow/signing/android_debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'Android'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "lib4.com.stackoverflow"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            proguardFile '/Users/anasabubacker/StackOverflow/proguard-android.txt'
        }
    }
}

// Map for the version code that gives each ABI a value.
ext.abiCodes = ['armeabi-v7a':1, x86:2, armeabi:3]

// For per-density APKs, create a similar map like this:
// ext.densityCodes = ['mdpi': 1, 'hdpi': 2, 'xhdpi': 3]

import com.android.build.OutputFile

// For each APK output variant, override versionCode with a combination of
// ext.abiCodes * 1000 + variant.versionCode. In this example, variant.versionCode
// is equal to defaultConfig.versionCode. If you configure product flavors that
// define their own versionCode, variant.versionCode uses that value instead.
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

    // Assigns a different version code for each output APK
    // other than the universal APK.
    variant.outputs.each { output ->

        // Stores the value of ext.abiCodes that is associated with the ABI for this variant.
        def baseAbiVersionCode =
                // Determines the ABI for this variant and returns the mapped value.
                project.ext.abiCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI))

        // Because abiCodes.get() returns null for ABIs that are not mapped by ext.abiCodes,
        // the following code does not override the version code for universal APKs.
        // However, because we want universal APKs to have the lowest version code,
        // this outcome is desirable.
        if (baseAbiVersionCode != null) {

            // Assigns the new version code to versionCodeOverride, which changes the version code
            // for only the output APK, not for the variant itself. Skipping this step simply
            // causes Gradle to use the value of variant.versionCode for the APK.
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    baseAbiVersionCode * 1000 + variant.versionCode
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```